# How can i understand this topic better, to be a better Programmer

Tags: javascript

i have a Question. I was thinking long Time about it, but poorly i don´t find a answer.
I know the every method.

My Question is about this code section:

```
var tr = order.every((i) => stock[i[0]] >= i[1]);
```

My Questions are:

1. `stock` is an Object. Why i must write as an array?
2. Why it is `i[0]` in `stock` and then `i[1]` ?
3. Why this code checks the nested Arrays in const order ?

```js
const order = [
  ["shirt", 5],
  ["shoes", 2]
];

const stock = {
  shirt: 50,
  height: 172,
  mass: 120,
  shoes: 6
};

var tr = order.every((i) => stock[i[0]] >= i[1]); /// return true
console.log(`tr:`,tr)
```

Comment: You're not treating `stock` as an array, you're using _bracket notation_. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors . See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Comment: @Teemu Thank you very much. And why it must be greater or equal to i[1] ?

Comment: That's a condition for an acceptable order, most likely it prevents you to buy more products than there are in the storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the square brackets can be used to access element inside the **array** by passing it's **index** e.g:

```
const arr = ["first", "second"];
const secondElement = arr[1] // index 1 means seconds element
```

and also square brackets can be used to access element inside the **object** by passing it's **key** e.g:

```
const obj = { first: 1, second: 2 };
const secondElement = object.second // Normal way to access value in object
const secondElementWithAnotherSyntax = object['second'] // another syntax, same thing
```

the cool thing about the other syntax shown is that you can pass variable to it, e.g :

```
const objKey = 'second'
const secondElement = obj[objKey]
```

Now let's look at your example, `i` is one element of the array `order`, which carries arrays itself, so `i` is also one of the two small arrays, `i[0]` is the string word in the beginning of the small arrays, so:

`i[0] // is either 'shirt' or 'shoes'`
and since `stocks` is an object that has those keys, you can access for example the value `50` by saying `stocks['shirt']` or as in your case, `stock[i[0]]` ;)

now your second question: why should it be `>= i[1]` ?
because the `order` second item , aka `i[1]` is the number of items required/ordered, so this should always be less that your stock, you can't by 5 shirts from a place that has only 3 in the stock :)

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest to try to use more expressive naming of the variables ?

An object property can be accessed through bracket notation, as in `stock[orderedProductName]` when using a variable - [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

A concise but imho more readable version can be written using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment?retiredLocale=it)

```js
const order = [
  ["shirt", 5],
  ["shoes", 2]
];

const stock = {
 shirt: 50,
 height: 172,
 mass: 120,
 shoes: 6,
};

// original version

let inStock = order.every((i) => stock[i[0]] >= i[1]); /// return true


// more verbose version
// check if every item in array order satisfies the condition
// let's cycle over the array calling the element we're working on
// orderItem

inStock = order.every( orderItem => {
  const orderedProductName = orderItem[0];
  const orderedProductQuantity = orderItem[1];
  // to access an object property we can use bracket notation
  const stockProductQuantity = stock[orderedProductName];
  
  // the condition to check: do we have enough products in stock ?
  return stockProductQuantity >= orderedProductQuantity;
});


// a concise variation could make use of destructuring assignment.
// Here, when we take the order item array, we immediately assign
// each of its elements to the appropriate variable
//
// orderItem[0] or first array element -> productName
// orderItem[1] or second array element -> orderedQuantity

inStock = order.every(([productName, orderedQuantity]) => 
  stock[productName] >= orderedQuantity
);

if(inStock) {
  console.log('pack and ship');
}
else {
  console.log('need to restock'); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**1. stock is an Object. Why i must write as an array?**

You can access properties of objects using brackets `[]`.

Why do we need this?

1. To be able to access properties of objects dynamically, e.g. when you are looping though keys and want to get the values

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log('Key : ' + key + ', Value : ' + data[key])
})
```

2. Sometimes there is no other way to access the value:

```
const json = {
  "id":"1",
  "some key with spaces": "48593"
};

console.log(json.some key with spaces); // obviously throws error
console.log(json['some key with spaces']); // prints "48593"
```

**2. Why it is i[0] in stock and then i[1] ?**

**3. Why this code checks the nested Arrays in const order ?**

The code goes through the orders, each order is an array so `i[0]` is the type of the order and `i[1]` is the quantity. the code checks if there are enough items in stock. To check if there are enough shirts you would do:

```
console.log(stock["shirts"] >= 5)
```

Thats what the code in your example does, it just passes the key (`"shirts"`) and quantity (`5`) dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

> The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value. If you want to read more [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

In your code snippet you are checking that every item in order array has quantity less than the quantity available in stock.

To access the properties of a object you can use square notation also like arrays. To read more [Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation)

Answer (score 0):

If you assigned more meaningful variables to the code you'd probably understand how this works better.

In one order (an array) we have two nested arrays. The first describes shirt/value, the other shoes/value. `every` is going to see if there is enough stock for both shirt and shoes by checking that the stockValue >= the items in the order.

When you `every` over the order array the callback for each iteration is one orderItem (`['shirt', 5]` first, then `['shoes', 2]` for the second). We can assign the first element of each array to a variable called `itemType`, and the second to a variable called `itemQty`.

So when you see `stock[i][0]` we can translate that in the new code as `stock[orderType]` which is [using bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) to locate the property value associated by that key in the stock object. We then check to see if that value >= than the `itemQty`.

```js
const order=[["shirt",5],["shoes",2]],stock={shirt:50,height:172,mass:120,shoes:6};

const result = order.every(orderItem => {
  const itemType = orderItem[0];
  const itemQty = orderItem[1];
  return stock[itemType] >= itemQty;
});

console.log(result);
```